# How to build a UI with a TextView on TOP and a ListView on BOTTOM?

Tags: android, listview

I check some examples on Internet, these examples just show how to single use `ListView`,it's boring.

We Always need to build a complex UI,and now, I want to write a UI that with two `View`,one of them is `TextView` on TOP,and take up 30% space, and another one is a `ListView`, it take the rest of space,70%.

If I just write like:

```
<LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"/>
<ListView
    ....
    android:layout_weight="7"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

it doesn't work....

Comment: add a textview as header to listview or use a relative layout add textview at the top and relarive to textview add listview at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Textview at the top and listview below the textview. Modify the below accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp" // specify the height required for textview
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can also add views as a header to listview.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use relative layout like:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="Large Text" />

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".3"/>
    <ListView
    ....
    android:layout_weight=".7"/>
</LinearLayout>
```